# Bash script syntax error

Tags: bash, syntax-error

```
anothervar = 1
while [$anothervar -lt 1 ] do
    read a
    if [ 42 = $a ]; then
       $anothervar = 2
    else
        echo $a
    fi
done
```

> get line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `done' error.

What did i do wrong ?

Comment: add a space after the first `[`

Comment: Also enclose variables in double quote. there should not be space in assignment =

Comment: `anothervar = 1
while [ $anothervar -lt 1 ] do
 read a
 if [ 42 = $a ]
 then
       $anothervar = 2
    else
     echo $a
    fi
done` 

I do it but return syntax error near unexpected token `done' error.

Comment: and a `;` after first `]`

Comment: http://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 2):

If you paste your shell script into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) you will see the following two shell script analysis messages for line 2 of your shell script:

1. You need a space after the [ and before the ].
2. Use semicolon or linefeed before 'do' (or quote to make it literal).

Your shell script after making the two corrections to line 2 suggested by the automated shell script analysis and changing the first line to `anothervar=0` so that the commands inside the while loop can be executed is:

```
anothervar=0
while [ $anothervar -lt 1 ]; do # fixes 2 errors in this line
    read a  
    if [ 42 = $a ]; then  
        anothervar=2
    else
        echo $a
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
anothervar=0
while [[ $anothervar -lt 1 ]]
do
    read a
    if [[ 42 = $a ]]
    then
        anothervar=2
    else
        echo $a
    fi
done
```

Voila, no semicolons, and spaces in the variables don't bother you anymore. ;-)